# Not able to evaluate condition properly in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure in MySQL to create a new city name in DB if it does not exist already.

Here's the script of my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SaveCity` (
  IN `inStateID` varchar(2), 
  IN `inCityName` varchar(30),
  OUT `outCityID` varchar(3)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE cityCode VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE maxCityID VARCHAR (3);
  /* Test whether CityName already exists */
  SELECT CityID INTO cityCode FROM cities WHERE StateID = inStateID AND CityName = inCityName;

  IF cityCode IS NULL THEN
      /* Fetch Max CityID */
      SELECT Max(CityID) INTO maxCityID FROM cities; 
      /* Increment CityID counter */
      SET cityCode = maxCityID + 1;
      INSERT INTO cities VALUES (cityCode, inStateID, inCityName);
  END IF;
  SET outCityID = cityCode;
  SELECT @outCityID;
END
```

If I write condition `IF cityCode IS NULL THEN`, it evaluates to FALSE for all values of `inCityName`, already existing or not, provided `inStateID` is the same.

If I write condition `IF (cityCode IS NULL) THEN`, it evaluates to TRUE for all values of `inCityName`. Again, if the condition evaluates to TRUE, the value returned from the procedure is **0** and a new record is NOT created for non-existing cities.

If I execute query `SELECT Max(CityID) FROM cities;` outside of the procedure, it returns an absolute value of CityID for city names already existing in database.

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sql
...
  -- DECLARE cityCode VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE cityCode VARCHAR(3); /* DEFAULT NULL */
...
  -- SELECT @outCityID;
  SELECT outCityID;
...
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a6fac16bc2fd8374bf9f45e8afefa84).

Comment: Without @, procedure won't return a value.

Comment: @kush.impetus: Return `@outCityID` within the stored procedure, it should be `NULL`, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e03dcb458ec010f3e1a100b438aa7d75).

Comment: @wchiwuito: Your were right. I was referring to a web article for beginners where the author mandated use of @. Thanks.

Comment: @kush.impetus: Check: [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) and [13.6.4.1 Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html).